# Расписание в C#

Tags: c#

добрый день! Есть у меня таблица  такая. Где: 1:1:4:0 - *день*:*час*:*минут*:*секунд*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо сделать чтобы таймер заработал как показано на таблице,с условием если `Час` то интервал таймера будет *минут и секунд*, если `Неделя` то *день и час*

```
string dbStr = row["shedule_dt_send_daytime"].ToString();
    string timenr = row["timer_name_ru"].ToString().ToUpper();
    DateTime dtbeg = Convert.ToDateTime(row["shedule_dt_beg"]);
    DateTime dtend = Convert.ToDateTime(row["shedule_dt_period_end"]);
      Console.Write(dbStr);


    //Разделяем строку на части
    string[] splitStr = dbStr.Split(':');




            // Получаем требуемый день недели.    
            int targetDayOfWeek = int.Parse(splitStr[0]);
            int targetHourofDay = int.Parse(splitStr[1]);
            int targetMinuteofHour = int.Parse(splitStr[2]);
            // получим русское имя дня недели
            string targetDayName = (new CultureInfo("ru-RU")).DateTimeFormat.DayNames[targetDayOfWeek % 7];
            Console.WriteLine("Таймер должен запуститься в " + targetDayName.ToUpper());



            // Получим текущий день недели
            int nowDayOfWeek = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
            string nowDayName = (new CultureInfo("ru-RU")).DateTimeFormat.DayNames[nowDayOfWeek % 7];


            DateTime startDay = DateTime.Now;

            if ((targetDayOfWeek != nowDayOfWeek) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(2))))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Время запуска уже прошло. ");
                // Посчитаем разницу между днями 
                int waitDay = (nowDayOfWeek < targetDayOfWeek) ? targetDayOfWeek - nowDayOfWeek : (7 - nowDayOfWeek) + targetDayOfWeek;
                Console.WriteLine("Нужно подождать еще: {0} дней", waitDay);
                // Вычислим время запуска
                startDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(waitDay);
            }



      // Вычислим время запуска
            DateTime startTime = new DateTime(startDay.Year, startDay.Month, startDay.Day, int.Parse(splitStr[1]), int.Parse(splitStr[2]), int.Parse(splitStr[3]));                
            if ((startTime > dtbeg) && (startTime < dtend))
            {

                    Console.WriteLine("Таймер будет запущен : {0}", startTime.ToString());


                // Узнаем разницу в миллисекундах, оставшуюся до запуска

                double waitTime_ms = (startTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine("До запуска осталось - {0} мc.", waitTime_ms);



                MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();


                myTimer.Interval = waitTime_ms;
                myTimer.s_id = Convert.ToString(row["shedule_id"]);
                myTimer.alg = Convert.ToString(row["meta_cod"]);
                myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
                myTimer.AutoReset = true;
                myTimer.datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime);
                myTimer.Enabled = true;



                //while (true) 
                // { int Hour = 23; int Minute = 42; int Seconds = 00; 
                // if ((Hour == System.DateTime.Now.Hour) && (Minute == System.DateTime.Now.Minute) && (Seconds == System.DateTime.Now.Second)) 



            }


    }    

       // myTimer.Dt_Begin = Convert.ToDateTime(row["shedule_dt_beg"]);
       // myTimer.Dt_Period_End = row["shedule_dt_period_end"];








     // } 

  }


       }



       Console.WriteLine("Идёт запись...");
       Console.WriteLine("Нажмите ENTER чтобы выйти");
       Console.Read(); static void OnTimeout(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            var s_id = ((MyTimer)sender).s_id.ToString();
            var alg = ((MyTimer)sender).alg.ToString();
            var date = ((MyTimer)sender).datetime;
            string st = "0";
            string com = "null";
            var beg = DateTime.Now;
            var end = DateTime.Now;
            var cr = DateTime.Now;
            var upd = DateTime.Now;

            //var comment = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).comment.ToString() };
            //var beg = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).Dt_Begin };
            //var end = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).Dt_Period_End };
            //string upd = string.Format("UPDATE ALg_stack SET dt_create=GETDATE() WHERE id=(SELECT id from alg_stack)");


            string sql = string.Format("Insert Into Alg_stack" +
               "(shedule_id,metaAlg,datetime, st, comment, dt_beg, dt_end, dt_create, dt_update) Values( @s_id,@alg, @date, @st, @com, @beg, @end, @create, @upd)");

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=192.168.1.156;Initial Catalog=ihd_aktobe;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd";

                cn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_id", s_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alg", alg);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", st);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@com", com);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@beg", beg);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@create", cr); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upd", upd);


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                cn.Close();



            }



        }
```

Comment: никто не хочет помогать?

Comment: Я не очень понял, что вы крутите. На каждую строчку надо запустить по таймеру? Почему не один таймер с минимальным периодом тогда уж? ПС: чем конкретнее вопрос, тем проще на него ответить, у вас вопроса нет, у вас просто кусок кода и вы сами не понимаете есть ли проблема.

Comment: я обновил вопрос

Comment: Ещё раз, что вы пытаетесь сделать и что не получается? Судя по первым строчкам кода, вы пытаетесь построить отображение, а судя по тексту - проблема с таймерами. Опишите проблему максимально точно, чтобы не читая весь ваш код было понятно, что не получилось и как вы пытались это сделать. Я пока вижу кучу подозрительных обращений к row по строковым ключам и ничего более.

Comment: есть одна таблица, которая имеет колонки `name_ru` и `dt_send` есть таймер который записывает данные в другую таблицу. Таймер должен работать с условием: если в `name_ru` выбрано `час`, то таймер должен работать по минутам , если выбрано из колонки `Неделя` , то таймер должен работать по дням и часам. Теперь понятно?

Comment: @Monk можете помочь?

Comment: Щас попробую накидать решение, но я не уверен, что правильно понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: можете доработать мой код. Там у меня таймер работает по дням, т.е. каждый день. А мне надо с условием. Каждый день, каждый час и каждый минут

Answer (score 1):

Итакс, что условно получилось. Берем данные из базы и пытаемся их распарсить в класс. Сам класс выглядит вот так:

```
  public class TimerData
  {
    public TimerPeriod Period { get; private set; }

    public TimeSpan TimeSpan { get; private set; }

    private TimeSpan FormateTimeSpanToPeriod(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
      switch (this.Period)
      {
        case TimerPeriod.Hour:
          return new TimeSpan(0, 0, minutes, seconds);
          break;
        case TimerPeriod.Week:
          return new TimeSpan(days, hours, 0, 0);
          break;
        default:
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
      }
    }

    public TimerData(string period, string timings)
    {
      this.Period = period == "Неделя" ? TimerPeriod.Week : TimerPeriod.Hour;
      var parsed = timings.Split(':').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
      this.TimeSpan = FormateTimeSpanToPeriod(parsed[0], parsed[1], parsed[2], parsed[3]);
    }
  }

  public enum TimerPeriod
  {
    Hour,
    Week
  }
```

Это минимально необходимые данные, по табличке. Теперь, как данные из таблички превратить в эти классы, а из классов потом создать таймеры:

```
  var sqlData = new List<string[]>();
  sqlData.Add(new[] { "Час", "1:1:4:0" });
  sqlData.Add(new[] { "Неделя", "1:0:0:0" });
  var td = sqlData.Select(s => new TimerData(s[0], s[1])).ToList();
  foreach (var timerData in td)
  {
    var timer = new Timer(timerData.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
    timer.Start();
  }
```

Вместо `sqlData` вы должны использовать что-то своё, свой источник данных для этих самых строк.
В итоге, в `td` у нас лежит список данных для таймеров.
Ну а дальше, я к сожалению не понял вашу магию с таймерами, так что просто в `foreach` можно для каждой записи создавать таймер, интервал которого получается легко из `timerData.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds`. Остальные параметры внутри `foreach` настраиваются по вкусу.

Comment: `this.Period = period == "Неделя" ? TimerPeriod.Week : TimerPeriod.Hour;` а что это означает?

Comment: Мне надо только добавить условия. Можно с `switch`. Не подскажете в моём коде где тут поставить условия?

Comment: Например, `switch case: "Неделя" ...`

Comment: @propro17 я почему и просил вас уточнить вопрос. По вашему вопросу, единственное что очевидно - надо общий TimeSpan изменять по периоду в другом столбце. Это и сделано. Что ещё вы ожидаете от кода - непонятно.